# Flash slideshow using Serif software

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm new to web coding and one of the older generation.
I have made a simple .swf slideshow using one of Serif's graphic software applications and inserted into a html page. I have discovered it doesn't show on an apple ipad. You can see (or rather, not)this quickly [here](http://www.johnleftwich.co.uk).
Now, can I use the original swf object within a javascript snippet or must I re-build the swf object in javascript?
Thanks for your help in anticipation.

John L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to struggle with getting Flash to work on iPads (or any iOS device for that matter, see [here](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/). There's no way to use the SWF snippet from a JS snippet either, so your best bet is to rebuild it for the web.

I'd recommend checking out [ImpressJS](http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/#/bored), or maybe [MagicHTML](http://www.magichtml.com/javascriptslideshow/) if you are feeling less technical. Both of these platforms will be cross browser/platform, so they should work just fine on an iPad. Good luck!